# How to assign "No Data" in all rows when the values are nulls

Tags: php, mysql

I have 40 columns rows that i want to fill in "No Data" automatically. This my code:

```
if (isset($people)) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM people  WHERE Name = '$people' LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
         
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            echo "
            <table>
            <tr><th>Name</th><td>". $row["Name"]."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Full Name</th><td>". $row["FullName"]."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Address</th><td>". $row["Address"]."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>BirthDate</th><td>". $row["BirthDate"]."</td></tr>
            <tr><th>Spouses</th><td>". $row["Spouses"]."</td></tr>
etc..
    </table>
```

I could use `if` statements in each `tr` like this, but i don't like it, there should be shorter way. `if($row['Spouses'] == ""){ echo "";} else{ echo $row["Spouses"];}`

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Maybe `echo $row["Name"] ?? 'No data';`

Comment: @user3783243 php 7. I tried using that inside the <table> and not working.

Comment: Do you get an error? Wrong output, no output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `??`. It takes care of null undefined values and you can use this as a replacement of ternary operator.
For example: `$row['spouses'] ?? ''`

You can study about this Null coalescing operator under this link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php